# String date to SQL date adding years

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, sqldatetime

I am using `SimpleDateFormat` to convert a date string to java.sql.date.
On converting, I am getting a issue, i.e. Year is getting added automatically.
Code:

```
String d="2012-12-04T08:48:00";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:SS");
java.util.Date date = null;
date = formatter.parse(d);
System.out.println("UTIL DATE: "+date);
System.out.println("SQL DATE: "+new Date(date.getTime()));
```

Output:

```
UTIL DATE:  Fri Dec 04 08:12:00 IST 2015  
SQL DATE:  2015-12-04
```

I should have got 2012 year in date, but it is adding up 3 years, Is there anything wrong in my code?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mm` represents minutes, `MM` is used to match the months - swap the field patterns

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Exactly! And the three years come from the month value "48", which is 3*12 months too much (=> 3 years).

Comment: There is a misstake in your solution. The time should `:mm:ss` I think

Comment: @Reimeus I edited your suggestion as you also misplaced some field patterns (minutes and seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Change your simple date format as of below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Here `mm` is minutes and `MM` for monts.